# ActionView::Template::Error: Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4

using:
Ruby 2.4.0p0
Rails 5.2.3
while running my test cases:
 having and error:

My testcase is like:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SubscriptionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "Can reach to index " do
    get subscriptions_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

end

Error:

```
SubscriptionsControllerTest#test_Can_reach_to_index_:
ActionView::Template::Error: Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/subscriptions/index.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_subscriptions_index_html_erb__900758959545617488_70234463713200'
    test/controllers/subscriptions_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SubscriptionsControllerTest>'
```

But the image load correctly when open the ui manually. could you suggest what is wrong.
in the view has image_tag as on line no 43.

```
 <%= image_tag 'tukacad_1.png', alt: '', class: "img-responsive" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside application.rb or test.rb write the following line

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

also run

```
rails assets:precompile
```